# Infinite dimensional representation theory question

Tags: representation-theory

I don't know much representation theory, but I was wondering, if the following holds:

> If $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation where $G$ is a compact Lie group and $V$ is an infinite dimensional representation then $V = \oplus_{i\in \mathbb{N}}V_i$, where each $V_i$ is an irreducible representation

I am wondering whether or not this above statement is true or not. Here $V$ is just an infinite dimensional vector space

Comment: Take $G=S^1$ and let it act by translations on $L^2(S^1)$. It is very easy to show that  the only irreps in that rep are $1$-dimensional, and that there are countably many of them (in fact, easy isoclass appears exactly once) That vector space is certainly not a direct sum of countably many 1-dimensional subspaces, though, because its dimension as a vector space is uncountable.

Comment: Of course, the question is much more interesting when you assume $V$ has countable dimension!

Comment: What continuity conditions are you imposing on the representation? I believe this is true when $G$ is a finite group (where we don't need to worry about continuity).

Comment: @KentaS Yes, I meant countable dimension

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem